# Are morphisms in a category single-valued/functional relations?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, relations, morphism

Am I correct that morphisms in a category are not necessary functional relations? That is, there can exist three objects $a$, $b$ and $c$ and an arrow $f$ such that we have both

$$a \xrightarrow{f} b \qquad\text{and}\qquad a \xrightarrow{f} c \quad ?$$

Do we still call arrows in such cases morphisms?

How do we call categories in which arrows are single-valued (or their opposite)?

Comment: A morphism in a category comes with a domain and a target. You cannot have two different targets.

Comment: In general, morphisms in a category have nothing to do with functions between sets. But you can define a "category of relations" $Rel(C)$ starting from a category $C$ with pullbacks, and some results about relations and functions transport: for example, $C$ embeds into $Rel(C)$, and morphisms in $Rel(C)$ coming from $C$ can be characterized in a certain way...